# Deriving an equation for solid of revolution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering, if there is any generic method that will help me find an explicit formula for a region bounded by a solid of revolution.

For example:
If I am given $z=x^2 $ which is a parabola, and rotate it by the $z$ axis, I obviously get the paraboloid $ z=x^2 + y^2 $ . But, how can I get the equation $z=x^2 + y^2 $ apriori, only by knowing that the resulted figure will be the solid of revolution of $z=x^2 $ .

In general, given a figure of the form $ z=f(x) $ that rotates about the $z$ axis for example. How can I find an explicit formula that will represent the obtained solid of revolution ?

Hope you'll be able to help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're rotating $z = f(x)$ about the $z$ axis, then the cross section at a particular value of $z$ will be circular.

In this case, it makes more sense to use cylindrical coordinates.

Then it's just $z = f(r),$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$  Literally replace $x$ with $r$ in your function.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You replace $z = f(x)$ by $z = f(r)$, where
$$
r^2 = x^2 + y^2.
$$